# function prototype node not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating an observable pattern in node like this.

./tableEvents.model.js

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var util = require('util');

module.exports = function(logger){

    function TableEvent(tableId){
        this.tableId = tableId;
        EventEmitter.call(this);
    }

    TableEvent.prototype.startTimer = function(){
        this.timer = setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('been 5 seconds, destroying');
            this.emit('destroy');
        }, 5000);
    };

    util.inherits(TableEvent, EventEmitter);

    return TableEvent;

};
```

Then in my route.js file

```
var TableEvent = require('../models/tableEvents.model')(logger);

var tableEvent = new TableEvent(table._id);

tableEvent.startTimer();

tableEvent.on('destroy', function(){
    console.log('destroyed');
    clearInterval(tableEvent.timer);
});
```

Now when it tries to tableEvent.startTimer(); I get this error in console

```
tableEvent.startTimer is not a function
```

Why is this?

Comment: When you have fixed the prototype overwriting, notice that [the `this` in the `setTimeout` callback won't work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572)

Comment: Thanks, I added var self = this;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`util.inherits()` overwrites the prototype of the inheriting object/constructor in order to accomplish its task. You need to make your prototype changes only *after* calling `util.inherits()`:

```
function TableEvent(tableId){
    this.tableId = tableId;
    EventEmitter.call(this);
}

util.inherits(TableEvent, EventEmitter);

TableEvent.prototype.startTimer = function(){
    this.timer = setTimeout(function(){
        console.log('been 5 seconds, destroying');
        this.emit('destroy');
    }, 5000);
};
```